# Windows 10 is blocking executed programs

Tags: windows-10-preview

I bought a computer from my friend, it is Lenovo Thinkpad W530. It was reset to factory defaults, and I logged in with my Microsoft account. I am sure that my account type is administrator.
My current Windows 10 build is 1709 (build 17046.1000)
I copied many files over the network, thus opened \computer\something_shared, and then Ctrl+a, Ctrl+X, Ctrl+V.

After that, I was about to install software, and I discovered weird behaviour.
If I run a setup program from the explorer, an UAC prompt appears. I then click Yes, and it looks like the setup wants to run, but it is blocked after a while. Blocked means that it is visible in the task manager, but no window is displayed. And the explorer windows from which I ran this setup becomes "not responding".
If I run the same setup from the administrator command prompt, then no UAC is displayed, and the setup installs normally, but only when it doesn't spawn another process as a step of installation.
So for example, Python 2.7.14 installed normally. But RAD studio 10.1 was blocked, because it spawned the LicenseManager as a part of the setup process.
Another example is update of NVDA, a screen reader I am using. It downloads, runs and then spawns something like nvda_update_xxx.exe. So a dialog "Updating NVDA, please wait..." is displayed forever.

I didn't install any secirity software. Also I tried to disable the Windows Defender temporarily, nothing helped until now.
I also tried to do another reset to factory default, with option "keep personal files", but the process was frozen, and I had to hardly shut down the computer, and fortunately it was restored.

So it is very difficult to install more complex software, and even if it installs normally, it doesn't run properly, for example if the program tries to run something like updater.exe from time to time like Notepad++.
Also it happened that some programs was misteriously unbvlocked, for example I was able to update NVDA the last time I tried.

Comment: Try repairing your windows. Check these videos, [repair at startup](https://youtu.be/gFR75FPEdhI) or [repair from settings](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z-HKlr_3o0Q)

Comment: Sorry, I am blind, so video has no real value for me.

Comment: The command sfc /scannow looks like everything is okay.

Comment: I didn't know that. Check these guides on pastebin, [repair from settings](https://pastebin.com/JvW3wFLd) and [repair at startup](https://pastebin.com/Gk2ZXHH1)

Comment: Given that it sounds like you've got copies of all your files somewhere else and you've not installed any other software, I wouldn't bother trying to resolve the problem. Instead download the Windows 10 drivers from the Lenovo website (https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/gb/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-w-series-laptops/thinkpad-w530/downloads) onto a USB stick and then do a full format and fresh install. You can then load the drivers from the USB stick and Windows 10 will happily re-activate when it gets online.

Comment: Windows 10 build 17046.1000 is a RS4 Windows Insider build.  You are NOT running 1709.

Comment: Ok, I am not sure, I copied this info from the winver message box. I have a czech localization, which looks like this, back translated to english: Version 1709 (operating system build 17046.1000)

Comment: Ramhound is right, you use an Insider build, where issues are expected. last build is 17063, test if you have the issue here